# Notes Client skipping numbers on '# in View' column

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse, ibm-domino

I am having a problem with IBM Notes version 9.0.1 where i have a view containing a '# in View' column as the first column. The view, as seen on the client, is skipping some numbers (on the printed view it skips the number 6151), while displaying them correctly on the Domino Designer preview:

**View on Notes Client:**

[image]

**View on Domino Designer preview:**

[image]

Whenever i run a script such as:

```
db.session.getCurrentDatabase();
thisView.db.getView("thisView");
entryCol = thisView.getAllEntries();
myEntry = entryCol.getNthEntry(6200);
```

I'll get an entry that follows the Designer numbering, instead of the 
Client numbering, which is very annoying because i can't search for documents on the Designer preview.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you or users on Notes Client have reader access to ALL documents? Check the readers fields.

Comment: Your Notes client graphic shows 6051 is missing. Your Designer preview graphic is showing 6060, 6061, and 6062. So are you sure they're really showing different documents?

Comment: @KnutHerrmann That solved part of the problem - the 6151 was indeed hidden from the client, i managed to see it by enabling full access in the administrator.
Now i need to figure out how to get the code to return the correct number, how do i go about changing the reader access of an agent?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Oh sorry, printed the wrong documents. Corrected now, thanks!

Comment: Can everyone read all documents? Do you want to change with the agent readers field to ALL users?

Comment: What type of agent is it?  Scheduled? Web? Note client?

Comment: @EnioMoura: '# in view' will never be accurate if you cannot see all of the entries because you're not allowed to see some of them; it's the Domino indexer that's counting, and it usually has read access to all entries. - Maybe you give us an idea of what you're trying to accomplish in the first place, because I don't quite get the "whenever I run a script..." part